# NodeJS recursion with dynamic number of parameters

Tags: node.js, recursion, dynamicparameters

I'm never to NodeJS and therefore struggling with a recursive multiplication function. The problem seems to be that in the recursion the input parameters are an array which is then assigned to the first value instead of value by value. Here's the code

```
const multiply = (factor1, ...factors) => {
  if (factors.length > 1){
    return Math.round(factor1 * multiply(factors) * scale) / scale;
  }
  const factor2 = factors[0];
  return Math.round(factor1 * factor2 * scale) / scale;
}
```

so calling with: `multiply(1,1,1,1)` leads to:

1. iteration:
   `factor1: 1, factors: [1,1,1]`
2. iteration:
   `factor1: [1,1,1], factors: Array(0)`

how can I achieve to have in the second iteration `factor1: 1, factors: [1,1]`, without checking if factor1 is an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is when you recursively call `multiply`, you don't pass each number as a separate parameter, you pass `factors` which is an array, therefore multiply gets a single array parameter.

Two ways of fixing this, either using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```
 multiply(...factors)
```

Or you can use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to invoke multiply and pass the parameters as an array

```
 multiply.apply(null, factors)
```

Comment: unfortunately not, factors in the second iteration becomes now an array of arrays..

Comment: @fsulser sorry, yeah, can see why, I misread. Let me update...

Comment: I think the first one would still lead to the same problem. But using apply seems to be the solution. Thank you James

Comment: @fsulser have you tried using the spread operator? It should be fine :)